# Excel Summing Up

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this, for example:

```
ColA   ColB  
X      1
Y      2
Z      3
X      4
```

I want to be able to summarize all values in Column B which

- Column A=X or
- Column A=Y.

The result should be 7 (1+2+4).

I did this:

`SUM(IF(COUNTIF(A:A,"X"),VLOOOKUP("X",A:B,2,),"0"), IF(COUNTIF(A:A,"Y"),VLOOOKUP("Y",A:B,2,),"0"))`

For some reason, it returns 3. It doesn't adds the second value of X for some reason.

Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: `=SUMIF(A:A,"x",B:B) + SUMIF(A:A,"y",B:B)` or (better) `=SUMIF(A:A,{"X","Y"},B:B)`

Comment: These are awesome, works like a charm. Thanks!!
Just a note: The second option doesn't work well, it returns the first instance of each.

Comment: will check out that second one.  I thought it had tested out OK.

Comment: That second version should have been: `=SUM(SUMIF(A:A,{"X","Y"},B:B))`

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((A2:A5="X")+(A2:A5="Y"))*(B2:B5))
```

If you select a portion of the formula and press Ctrl+=, you can see how it is evaluated.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((({TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE})+({FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE}))*(B2:B5))
```

Now when those two arrays are added together, the TRUE is coerced to a 1 and the FALSE to a zero.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(({1;1;0;1})*(B2:B5))
```

The resulting array of 1's and 0's is multiplied by the array from B2:B5.

```
=SUMPRODUCT({1;2;0;4})
```

And summed up to 7.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula returns an error (tooo many o’s!) but with `VLOOKUP`s `3`.  Since the problem is not with `Y`, simplify the issue by taking out that part of the formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,"X"),VLOOKUP("X",A:B,2,),"0")
```

This results in `1`. But so does:

```
=VLOOKUP("X",A:B,2,)
```

Hence `COUNTIF(A:A,"X")` (which returns `2` because there are two instances of `X`) does not actually help. Replaced with `7`, or `103` or `5=5` - no difference.

You are obviously aware that plain vanilla VLOOKUP stops ‘searching’ once it finds the first instance that meets its ‘rules’ but unfortunately inserting a `2` with COUNTIF is not enough to ‘tell’ VLOOKUP “after finding the first match, now go off and find the second as well”.

So an answer to your question as expressed is “Yes. VLOOKUP cannot be made aware of multiple instances with the =COUNTIF function.”